# Inner DIVs scrolling/sliding up to the top of the DIV they inhabit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a column of `div` elements set within another `div` element.  The parent or main `div` is set to a particular height and scrollable.

When I call a function, based on the ID of the inner div I call, I want the inner `div` to animate/scroll to the top of the main `div`.

Note, I don't want the `div` elements to change position - just to scroll up while staying in the original position.

[JsFiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/fk3gzt8j/20/)

Here's my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', goStart);

function goStart(event) {
  // Call the function
  clicknext('3');
};

function clicknext(id) {
  jQuery('#subdiv-' + id).animate({
    scrollTop: (jQuery('#main-div').offset().top)
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#main-div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-div">

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-1">
    DIV 1
  </div>

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-2">
    DIV 2
  </div>

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-3">
    DIV 3
  </div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="TRIGGER THE FUNCTION" id="triggerbutton">
```

Comment: You could make it slide up...

Comment: That’s the goal.  :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't make myself clear - can't you just use jQuery animations, then when that's over, actually clone the div to the top of the main?

Comment: Not following.  Why would I need to clone it?  Is it not possible just to slide it?  My jQuery animate call isn’t doing anything, but. It sure why.

Comment: Sorry - in essence, modify the HTML so the div is actually at the top of your HTML code

Comment: No worries. Still not following.  Basically I have another function calling this one based on a loop.  I want each div to slide up when the id is called from the loop.  I’m open to doing it however, but this is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the scroll value is relative to **parent** offsetTop  ('#main-div')

```js
const TabInner = [
  (document.getElementById('subdiv-1').offsetTop - document.getElementById('main-div').offsetTop),
  (document.getElementById('subdiv-2').offsetTop - document.getElementById('main-div').offsetTop),
  (document.getElementById('subdiv-3').offsetTop - document.getElementById('main-div').offsetTop)
  ];

var Trigg_ref = 1;
triggerbutton.onclick = function()
{
  Trigg_ref = (Trigg_ref +1) % 3;
  clicknext(Trigg_ref);
};


function clicknext(id)
{
  jQuery('#main-div').animate({
    scrollTop: TabInner[id] 
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.inner {
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
#main-div {
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:#EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-div">
  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-1">
    DIV 1
  </div>
  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-2">
    DIV 2
  </div>
  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-3">
    DIV 3
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="TRIGGER THE FUNCTION" id="triggerbutton">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to CSS Transition Animation on Transform for Optimal Performance**
New Answer: https://jsfiddle.net/t5f6e9k3/
You should check out https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count

```
    .inner {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition: transform linear 300ms, opacity linear 300ms;
  }
#main-div {
 display:inline-block;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#EFEFEF;
 position:relative;
}
.inner:not(.active) {
  transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
    function clicknext(id) {
    var active = document.querySelectorAll('.inner.active');
  for(var i=0; i<active.length; i++){
    active[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    var current = document.querySelector('#subdiv-'+id);
  if(!current.classList.contains('active')){
        current.classList.add('active');
  }


}
```

Original answer:
You are sliding the wrong element.
If you are wanting a 'window' type of scroll effect that just scrolls content into the viewing container: https://jsfiddle.net/yo45601j/1/

```
  var main = jQuery('#main-div');
  var elm = jQuery('#subdiv-'+id);
  main.animate({
      scrollTop: (elm[0].offsetTop - main[0].offsetTop)
  },500);
```

or reset just to 0
https://jsfiddle.net/yo45601j/

```
function clicknext(id) {

  jQuery('#main-div').animate({
      scrollTop:0
  },500);


}
```

Comment: This was also a good answer and helped me finish this up.  Thanks @silverandrew

Answer (score 0):

The element position property must be absolute to animate it over the other elements. Try this

```js
document.addEventListener('click', goStart);

function goStart(event) {
  // Call the function
  clicknext('3');
};

function clicknext(id) {
  jQuery('#subdiv-' + id).css("position","absolute").animate({
    top: 0
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#main-div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-div">

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-1">
    DIV 1
  </div>

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-2">
    DIV 2
  </div>

  <div class="inner" id="subdiv-3">
    DIV 3
  </div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="TRIGGER THE FUNCTION" id="triggerbutton">
```

Comment: Nah I wasn't wanting the DIVs to get out of order, so they would need to scroll up rather than pop-up.  Thanks for the answer though.